# Repeated "InvaidTemplate" error when test running the flow

Tags: power-automate

I'm currently working on a Power Automate flow to send out an alert if a hourly email service is not received within 1h 30mins from the last email. The main idea is to extract the date time of the last email sent which will be on the subject of the hourly email. I will then use the date time and flow it through a condition to compare with a date time 1h 30mins before the current timing. If the date time of the email is less than that of the latter date time, the condition will be deemed as true and a message will be sent out on Teams, alerting others about the missing hourly email.

[Picture of Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfeol.png)

The picture of the flow is linked above. Basically, I start of with a recurrence trigger that runs every hour. Thereafter, I use Get Emails (V3) to extract the last email sent out by this hourly email service. After Get Emails (V3), I added Compose where it was supposed to extract out the subject and focus specifically on the date time on the subject.

Here's the expression code for the first Compose:

```
split(split(split(outputs('Get_emails_(V3)')?['body/value'], 'subject:')[1], 'System Health Diagnosis ')[1], '-')[0]
```

Thereafter, there will be a second compose to convert the date time from the subject into ISO date time format. I will then use the ISO date time format to compare it to the condition.

However, I have been experiencing errors at the first compose. The error is as follows,

> 

InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'split' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Array'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#split for usage details.'.

Thanks in advance for any reply. Will provide more information if requested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to split all emails (which is an array).

If you only want to split the last email you could try this expression instead:
*This expression uses an index [0] to get the last e-mail from the Get emails (v3) action.*

```
split(split(outputs('Get_emails_(V3)')?['body/value'][0]['subject'], 'System Health Diagnosis ')[1], '-')[0]
```